# How save add items on memory after close app?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, state

Why my add items dont save on memory? When I back to RootViewController my list disappear, What happened ?

Code for add and work fine...

```
- (IBAction) addButtonPressed: (id)sender {
 NSLog(@"Add button pressed!");

 addPosto *addposto = [[addPosto alloc] initWithNibName:@"postoDictionary" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *addNavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addposto];
 addposto.postoArray = self.poscomb;
 [self presentModalViewController:addNavCon animated:YES];
 [addposto release];
 [addNavCon release];

}
```

On RootViewController select row "Meus Postos"

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   postoLista *codigo = [[postoLista alloc] initWithNibName:@"postoLista" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:codigo animated:YES];
   [codigo release];

}
```

So I need to know how I archieve list on memory after add items, thanks for attention!

Eduardo Parucker.

Comment: How do you update poscomb after you save in addposto.postoArray?  You didn't post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talk to Leonardo of Instants Games on Brazil he implement a singleton and resolved my problem, so I think thats it! thanks for all helps!